# Why my external jars are not included when creating an eclipse update site

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, apache-commons, update-site

I've created an eclipse plugin project with support for a DSL. The problem that i'm facing is i'm using some external libraries like apache commons, antlr,jface.text etc. It is running fine when i run from inside eclipse. But once i make an update site project, and install from it, none of the dependencies are copied or taken care of.It installs properly, but once i open a view which uses any of these libraries, it fails to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export them.

Go under properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export and mark the libraries there

On Slider "Libraries" you can add them and after that you can mark them in Order and Export

Comment: thanks logi..But still the issue is remaining..:-( now during installation it is saying Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: ******Components 1.0.0.201402052234 (***Components.feature.group 1.0.0.201402052234)
  Missing requirement: XXXX XXX Viewer 1.0.0.201402052234 (org.xxxxx.xxxstudio.l 1.0.0.201402052234) requires 'package org.apache.commons.compress.archivers 1.5.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: xxxxxxComponents 1.0.0.201402052234

Comment: has it something to do with feature project creation??